# handle php error after foreach success

Tags: php, loops, pdo, foreach

I tried catch if do CRUD in foreach loop, if success loop finish push message into array, below is my function, I push message after foreach is it correct?

```
// .. defined response_message array

try {
  foreach ($data as $i => $each_data) {
    $sql = "UPDATE tag_0 SET sequence = :sequence WHERE id = :id";
    $stmt = $connect_db_read->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $each_data['id']);
    $stmt->bindValue(':sequence', $each_data['sequence']);
    $stmt->execute();
  }

  // here
  $success_message = 'success_message: store in database success';
  array_push($response_message['success_message'], $success_message);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  $debug_message = $e->getMessage();
  array_push($response_message['debug_message'], $debug_message);
  $error_message = "error_message: ? database";
  array_push($response_message['error_message'], $error_message);
}


$data = array();
$data['response_message'] = $response_message;


return $data;
```

Comment: ?? no, above is all..

Comment: How is `$response_message['success_message']` in the scope of your function? `$response_message['success_message']` is `undefined`.

Comment: @PHPglue  I defined before

Comment: @PHPglue nah.. it can use status to check one sql execute like this `$status = $stmt->execute();`  but I'm tried to find how to check all sql execute success and finish than send a message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$stmt->execute();` will return true when a query is succesful.

This does not mean the record was updated , it only means that the query executed without error.

To be really sure, you have to check the number of affected rows using `rowCount()`

Try this approach:

```
$error_counter = 0;
$sql = "UPDATE tag_0 SET sequence = :sequence WHERE id = :id";
$stmt = $connect_db_read->prepare($sql);  
foreach ($data as $i => $each_data) {
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $each_data['id']);
    $stmt->bindValue(':sequence', $each_data['sequence']);
    $status = $stmt->execute();
    $row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
    if($status && $row_count > 0){
        $success_message = 'Successful update for sequence id ='.$each_data['id'];
        array_push($response_message['success_message'], $success_message);
    }else{
        $failed_message = 'update failed for sequence id ='.$each_data['id'];
        array_push($response_message['fail_message'], $fail_message);
        $error_counter++;
    }
}
```

You should also prepare once than bind and execute in the loop, no need to send the query back to the db at each iteration.

---

I added another way to track with a variable `$error_counter` if the value is `0` then all records where updated.

```
//check after the loop
if($error_counter === 0){
    echo 'All UPDATES SUCCESSED !!!!';
}else{
    echo 'NOT ALL SUCCESFUL !';
}
```

Alternatively you can achieve the same using the count of the failed messages:

```
(count($response_message['fail_message'])===0)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, this is check each times, but I tried to find is how to after all foreach success than push one success message or push one failed message

Comment: I dont understand ? this is exactly what I did. maybe refresh the page @user1775888

Comment: mm.. you did check `if($status && $row_count > 0)`and push message `$success_message = 'Successful update for sequence id ='.$each_data['id'];
        array_push($response_message['success_message'], $success_message);`  in foreach loop , but I only want one message if all success or if one fail